# Are there any standard methods people use to ensure safety when using stripe?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, payment

Stripe has a lot of options for customization, but this is my first payment gateway so I'm wondering if there are standards out there that should be included in every implementation to ensure credit card safety. For example, should I enable stripe's zip code verification or not? An extension of that question is how does stripe check if addresses and zip codes are valid in countries other than the US (does it even?)?

Comment: Usually, the best practice is to use as many security features as possible, because it increases your chances of resolving a dispute in your favour if there is a fraudulent transaction or a chargeback. But, your UX/marketing team might think otherwise, and prefer that sacrifices are made in order to improve UX/conversion, so i't kind of a tradeoff. Use as many security features as you can afford. Regarding zip code verification, Stripe themselves have a good article https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-avs

Comment: Thanks. In that article, would `address_line1` for example be automatically verified by stripe as long as you include that attribute in your submission form for the user to put in their own address?

Comment: That sounds like a good question to ask Stripe support.